# Separate a string and an integer in one line Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new with Python. I have a exercise and it's input has the form like this:

```
BANANA FRIES 12
POTATO CHIPS 30
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
```

So, what i can do to divide the input into 2 parts: a string and an integer?

Comment: Are there some extra requirements?What have you tried?

Comment: This forum doesnt serve to answer your homework questions. What have you tried and what isn't working for you?

Comment: I have tried map(str, input.split()) before.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [47]: a = """BANANA FRIES 12
    ...: POTATO CHIPS 30
    ...: APPLE JUICE 10
    ...: CANDY 5"""

In [48]: [i.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for i in a.split("\n")]
Out[48]:
[['BANANA FRIES', '12'],
 ['POTATO CHIPS', '30'],
 ['APPLE JUICE', '10'],
 ['CANDY', '5']]
```

Use `rsplit(maxsplit=1)` - split from right side and split only once.

As you need integer

```
In [51]: temp = []

In [52]: for i in a.split("\n"):
    ...:     split = i.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    ...:     split[1] = int(split[1])
    ...:     temp.append(split)
    ...:
    ...:

In [53]: temp
Out[53]: [['BANANA FRIES', 12], ['POTATO CHIPS', 30], ['APPLE JUICE', 10], ['CANDY', 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
i = '''BANANA FRIES 12
POTATO CHIPS 30
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
'''
split = [l.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for l in i.split('\n')]
split = [l[0], int(l[1]) for l in split]
```

`split` is now equal to:

```py
[['BANANA FRIES', '12'],
 ['POTATO CHIPS', '30'],
 ['APPLE JUICE', '10'],
 ['CANDY', '5']]
```

Comment: It's very helpful. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What You can do is use a regex pattern to seperate the string and Integer, Something like this:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)") 
res = pattern.match(inputstring).groups()
print(str(res))
```

Comment: yep, i usually use pattern to match strings i need in Java. But i think this is a normal exercise so i must have a simpler solution. Thanks for your help!